# Build, syntax-check, parse and evaluate a query

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I am building a query in a textarea with different conditions selected from the html controls. Also users are open to do modification to it.

Client side:
For the below list of condition:

```
a(1, 3) > 20
b(4, 5) < 90
c(3, 0) = 80
```

I form a query:

```
a(1, 3) > 20 and b(4, 5) < 90 or c(3, 0) = 80
```

On the server side this has to be parsed, lookup and call each function with arguments. (a, b and c are the functions)

I want to check for the query syntax (not sure at the client side or the server side) before processing it.
For example if the user enters incorrect function / arguments or they use incorrect operators.

Appreciate your suggestions and feedback.

PS: Using python

Comment: How do you know that the first two are supposed to be "and"'ed, while the third is to be "or"'ed?

Comment: Any combination accepted this is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) has a simple [expression example](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html) that will get you most of the way there.

Comment: +1, I would advise PLY, if only for being able to grow the syntax without redoing regexp.